# How do you set up javapns (push notifications for iOS)?

Tags: java, iphone, ios, push-notification

I have had a look at the documentation / wiki for javapns. http://code.google.com/p/javapns/

Unfortunately, what should be obvious is anything but obvious to me.

How do I set up a working push notification server? As in, there's a .jar file, but I would appreciate more info than that. Do I need to run this in Tomcat?  Is there a working example?'

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have used [Java APNS](https://github.com/notnoop/java-apns) in the past. It has a BSD License and did a perfect job and was quite easy to use once the certificates were set up. All in all it is not a dead-simple task to set up Push notifications, but I usually got usable debug output if there was anything not quite working yet.

A good thing about this solution is that you can run it stand alone `java -jar MyAPNSPusher` and trigger it with some cron job or include the logic in some `.war` file. I also found that the library was quite lightweight and I guess you can also find it in a maven repo.

### Example from the Readme.markdown

To send a notification, you can do it in two steps:

1. Setup the connection

   ```
   ApnsService service =
       APNS.newService()
       .withCert("/path/to/certificate.p12", "MyCertPassword")
       .withSandboxDestination()
       .build();
   ```
2. Create and send the message

   ```
   String payload = APNS.newPayload().alertBody("Can't be simpler than this!").build();
   String token = "fedfbcfb....";
   service.push(token, payload);
   ```

`[...]`

### Alternatives

If hosting your own server solution is too cumbersome then you can fallback to a thirdparty service which might often be a good thing because hosting a server with such a service running on it is probably often underestimated. With those services you usually pay a tiny amount (fractions of a cent) for a push message. Two that I have come across are

- http://www.ilime.com

  > **Edit** As of July 1, 2011, the iLime API has been discontinued as a public service.
- http://urbanairship.com/

Comment: Thank you.  I guess my real question is more of the setup/plumbing that has to happen inside a Java Server before writing any code. Time and again the greatest barrier to Java for newbies is the overhead in setting a project up. Java APNS is supposed to be a server, no? There are no instructions on how to set up the server part. Fair enough if we knowing java server admin is a prerequisite, but I am certain that newbies will be lost b/c that part isn't clear and I hope that the docs make that clearer.

Comment: It is common for developers to start with the use case "I've been told to set up push notifications". And in the wiki, at least if my case is at all representative, I don't see anything that says "download tomcat".  Or "you need to know how to set up a java server".  Or maybe I am mistaken. Are there any fully working sample projects that aren't code snippets? I'm not sure how to make my ios app talk to a standard java project unless it's through webservices, which would require a java-based server, no?

Comment: Maybe you should consider using a third-party service, since they are really cheap and will get you up and running quickly. And than when you see the need for it or want to save money because you need to send millions of push messages, you could come back to setting up your own server...

Comment: Yes, I may need to do that first. Appreciate the help

Comment: Your application won't talk to the "Push Program". It works differently. Your Java App (be it server based or run "naked") talks to the Apple servers and delivers the Push notification to those servers and Apple then sends the push notification to your iPhone App. If your application then needs to download some other data from this server, well this is another story then and not directly related to the Push messages anymore.

Answer (score 5):

JavaPNS is a java library used within your project. It can only be used to connect to the Apple Push Notification Servers, using the certificates that you create on the Apple Developer Tools Website.

So, if I'm reading your question properly, this is not a stand-alone program and probably not what you want.

If you are trying to send push notifications to Apple iOS devices, then this IS what you want, but you need to write the rest of your application first, then add this library to it.

Comment: After adding the library how to send message using this

Comment: Look thru the wiki page...: https://code.google.com/archive/p/javapns/wikis/WorkingExample.wiki